# How to add cells to UITableView that has no controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I want to add some data from a `NSMutableArray` to my `UITableView`. I have made an `IBoutlet` which is called `lessonsTable`. All the tutorials i can find assumes that the `UITableView` has its own controller, so they change a method about adding cells. But i don't have a separate controller class for my `UITableView`, it is just a view floating in another controller.

I've tried

```
[lessonsTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:appDelegate.lessonsArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

But it didn't solved the problem.

`lessonsArray` has the data that i want to insert to my `UITableView`

Comment: you can't add data from an array to a table view. The array contains the data rendered by the view

Comment: can't i create a cell an add it to tableview from array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a dedicated view controller, but you do need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. You can't just send an array to a table and expect it to figure out the details for you.